# Does ServletRequestListner work for REST api calls from postman?

Tags: java, servlets, event-handling, postman

So, I have to restructure an application and make micro-services for the features. Now the application previously, was JEE application and had a **RequestListener** which implements **ServletRequestListener** interface. As far as I know request listener should be called automatically when the application fires up, **and detect the Servlet Requests and Responses**.
As I have only one module , that is the microservice now and the whole application is not yet running. I want  the default methods of

**ServletRequestListener**

i.e

```
public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent requestEvent)
```

&&

```
public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent requestEvent)
```

to get called every time I make and REST api call through postman.Just like it would have worked for a JEE application's servlet requests.
I need to do this to track the API activity stats.

I have tried a lot and search a lot of blogs and articles online. There is no such thing listens to API calls. Is there a way to do it? You suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS uses some of the servlet layer but it's mostly separate.  If you want to have a method called when your service is called you'll want something like:

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;


@Provider
public class ContainerRequestFilterImpl implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {  
       // this method will be called for JAX-RS requests
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working actually. Is there any sort of configuration or registration that needs to be done in Spring for this containerrequestfilter?? I tried with doFilter method of JavaServlet Filter. But in that case only the doFilter is executing and the resource mapped to that URI is not getting executed.